# Adding local users not in Active Directory in VisualSVN Server

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server, visualsvn

I am using VisualSVN. I am wondering whether if I use subversion authentication, I can easily link my active directory and also be able to add local users who are not part of the active directory.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered to create a new local Windows user account on the server computer? You can grant permissions to this account to access the repositories and it should be able to authenticate to VisualSVN Server via Basic Windows authentication. Read more about authentication types in VisualSVN Server in the article [KB39: Understanding VisualSVN Server Authentication options](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00039/).

Single VisualSVN Server instance can be configured to use either Windows/AD-based security or dedicated Subversion accounts. The current VisualSVN Server version do not support mixed-mode authentication on a single server instance.

If you want to use mixed-mode authentication and authorization that implies using Subversion dedicated accounts and Windows accounts altogether, it is possible to deploy 2 VisualSVN Server instances. In other words, you can install 2 instances of VisualSVN Server each using different authentication type.

You could deploy two VisualSVN Server Enterprise Edition instances enabled for Multisite Repository replication feature and configure one server to use Windows authentication and the other one to use Subversion authentication. External users should access the server that has Subversion authentication enabled and your internal users should access the one configured for Windows authentication. In such case you'd be required to maintain user/group list and access rules for non-domain users separately.

- [Multisite Repository Replication](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/multisite-replication/)
- [KB68: Getting started with Multisite Repository Replication](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00068/)